# What triggers a download count?

Tags: soundcloud

Many tracks on SoundCloud offer a download option. However, most of these link to an external website. I'm trying to record how many times the free download button is pressed and in the SoundCloud API it shows that the number of downloads is counted. Now I am not sure when a download is counted since a popular song such as this one https://soundcloud.com/intrepidsmusic/i-dont-care (track ID: 242105069) that links to a Bandcamp page apparently has a download count of 0. Could somebody explain to me how this information is tracked and what is actually counted?

Comment: He Sam, did my answer help you? You should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/242209) if one has helped you, or feel free to follow up with any questions.

Comment: Oops, sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow, I accepted it! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That link to Bandcamp is not technically the "download" link the SoundCloud API is referring to.  Only certain tracks that can be downloaded directly from SoundCloud, such as [this](https://soundcloud.com/the-orphan/the-police-king-of-pain-orphan) one.  The "download" count is only incremented if the owner has provided a file for download through SoundCloud directly (and is incremented every time a user clicks the "download" button).

Answer (score 0):

JAL is correct.  Those are not technically download links and are instead referred to as "purchase" links.

One thing you could do, is pull the purchase link URL from the JSON and add a click event to whatever you're building.  This will take the user to the external download site. You can track how many times that button has been clicked, but I can't think of a way to see if a user follows through with the actual download on the external site.